# Enumerating over matrix element values in Table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a $N$ dimensional array $M$, and a function $f(\{M_{i}\})$ in terms of the array elements, where each matrix element $M_{i}$ can be 0 or 1. I'd like to construct a table

```
Table[f(\{M_{ij}\}), {M_{1},0,1},{M_{2},0,1},...,{M_{N},0,1}]
```

For a given N, I can write down the code to construct the table, but for general N, it there a convenient way to write the above code? Namely, I'd like to keep N as an input variable.

As an example, let us use

```
n=3;
Mat=Table[M[i],{i,1,n}];
```

and define f as the sum of all the elements in Mat. so the table I want to construct is

```
Table[Sum[M[i],{i,1,n}], {M[1],0,1},{M[2],0,1}, {M[3],0,1}]
```

The outcome is

```
{{{0, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}}
```

Of course, when I change n to other values, I need to rewrite the code for the table. So there should be a way for us to construct the table without modifying the code.

Comment: It seems to me that you want to `Map` your function $f$ on each element of the matrix $M$. Would `Map[f, M, {2}]` do what you want?

Comment: $f$ depends on every element of $M$, not just one particular element. So I think we need some more complicated form.

Comment: Can you give an example input with the desired example output?  That would help.

Comment: @user34104 Yes, so you will have defined `f[mi_] := <do something with the mi value>` so for each different value in $M$, $f$ will do whatever you want with it. I second @march’s request though. If you show us an example of input and desired output, this will be much easier.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated with an example.

Comment: Have you seen `Tuples`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From one example it is not clear what you want for other than `n = 3`, perhaps

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Mat[n_] := 
 Table[Sum[M[i], {i, 1, n}], 
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ ({M[#], 0, 1} & /@ Range[n])]]

Mat[3]

(* {{{0, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}} *)

Mat[5]

(* {{{{{0, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}}, {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 
     3}, {3, 4}}}}, {{{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}}}, {{{2, 
     3}, {3, 4}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 5}}}}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Working from your example:

```
ClearAll[Mat]
Mat[n_Integer] := Nest[Partition[#, 2, 1] &, Range[0, n], n - 1]

Mat[3]

(* Out: {{{0, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}} *)
```

Checking with your desired output:

```
% == {{{0, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}} (* Out: True *)
```

Also:

```
Mat[5]

(* Out: 
{{{{{0, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}}, {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}}}}, {{{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}}}, {{{2, 3}, {3, 4}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 5}}}}}
*)
```